# Sorting the main diagonal of a matrix

Tags: sorting, matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix, and its elements on the main diagonal aren't sorted, so I need a function that will return new matrix with sorted elements on the main diagonal. I can't understand why this won't work.

```
   Function[A_] := Module[{res, diagonal = {}, m, n},
   {m, n} = Dimensions[A];
   Table[AppendTo[diagonal, A[[i, i]]], {i, 1, m}];
   dijagonal = SelectionSort[diagonal];
   Table[A[[i, i]] = dijagonal[[i]], {i, 1, m}];
   Return[A // MatrixForm];
   ];
```

Selection sort works.

This can be an example of matrix:

```
   A={{60, 10, 68, 72, 64},{26, 70, 32, 19, 29},{94, 78, 86, 59, 17},
 {77, 13, 34, 39, 0}, {31, 71, 11, 48, 83}}
```

When I run it, this shows up:

Set::setps: {{60,10,68,72,64},{26,70,32,19,29},{94,78,86,59,17},{77,13,34,39,0},{31,71,11,48,83}} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issues

- you can not define your own function named `Function`.  (Generally avoid using any symbol beginning with a capital to avoid conflicts )
- you can not modify the the input argument, so make a copy
- just use `Sort` not `SelectionSort`

I made a couple of other changes that are more stylistic as well:

```
  function[A0_] :=
     Module[{res, diagonal = {}, m, n, A = A0},
     {m, n} = Dimensions[A];
     diagonal = Table[A[[i, i]], {i, 1, m}];
     dijagonal = Sort[diagonal];
     Do[A[[i, i]] = dijagonal[[i]], {i, 1, m}]; A]

 function[A] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

note you can do all this inline:

```
 ReplacePart[ A, 
      Table[ {i, i} -> (Sort@Diagonal[A])[[i]], {i, Length@A} ]]
```

or

```
 (A + DiagonalMatrix[Sort@# - # &@Diagonal[A]])
```